# How to get a bufio.Writer that implements io.WriteCloser

Tags: go, io

I want to extend existing code that writes data to a file in an unbuffered way.

The code expects a writer that implements the `io.WriteCloser` interface. Therefore just wrapping the existing file with a `bufio.Writer` does not work, as it does not implement this interface.

How can I make a `bufio.Writer` to implement and pass the necessary close call to the underlaying file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`io.WriteCloser`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#WriteCloser) is the interface:

```
type WriteCloser interface {
        Writer
        Closer
}
```

Which ultimately "prescribes" these 2 methods:

```
Write(p []byte) (n int, err error)

Close() error
```

[`bufio.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Writer) already has a `Write()` method, so to make it a `WriteCloser`, only a `Close()` method is needed.

Extending `bufio.Writer` with a noop `Close()` method:

```
type MyWriteCloser struct {
    *bufio.Writer
}

func (mwc *MyWriteCloser) Close() error {
    // Noop
    return nil
}
```

A value of type `*MyWriteCloser` is now a `WriteCloser`. This is the easiest extension. Using it:

```
bw := bufio.NewWriter(w)

mwc := &MyWriteCloser{bw}
```

Although we can –and we should– add a more meaningful `Close()` method. As `bufio.Write` does buffered writes, we should flush its internal buffer before we declare it closed:

```
func (mwc *MyWriteCloser) Close() error {
    return mwc.Flush()
}
```

Also note that since `bufio.Write` cannot be closed (does not provide a `Close()` method), this will not close its underlying `io.Writer`, this is just to conform to the `io.Closer` and `io.WriteCloser` interfaces.

If you also want to close the underlying file, you also have to store it, and after calling `bufio.Flush()` (to make sure everything is written out), given it's not returning any errors, you may proceed to also close the file.

This is how it could look like:

```
type MyWriteCloser struct {
    f *os.File
    *bufio.Writer
}

func (mwc *MyWriteCloser) Close() error {
    if err := mwc.Flush(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return mwc.f.Close()
}
```

Using it:

```
// Open a file:
f, err := os.Open("myfile.txt")
if err != nil {
    panic(err) // Handle error
}

mwc := &MyWriteCloser{f, bufio.NewWriter(f)}
defer mwc.Close()

// use mwc
```

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, the underlaying file would remain unclosed, right?

Comment: @Robert, you can as well store the original `io.Writer` in `MyWriteCloser`—along with `bw` wrapping it,—and call its `Close()` after calling `Flush()` on the `bw`; calling `Flush()` *(which returned no error)* guarantees the `bufio.Writer` had passed the pending data through and hence is not bufferning anything, and it's now safe to call `Close()` on the underlying file.

Comment: @Robert See edited answer, included how the file could also be closed.